# Converting reach reported at $1\sigma$ to $95\%$ C.L

Tags: particle-physics, statistics

I'm comparing these two papers, Refs. [(1)](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1411.4088.pdf) and [(2)](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1806.08499.pdf), and they both constraint the ratio of doubly-charged scalar mass ($M_{H^{\pm\pm}}$) and its Yukawa coupling $(f_{ee})$ to electrons.

In Ref. [(1)](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1411.4088.pdf), the MOLLER collaboration sets the lower bound at
$$\frac{M_{H^{\pm\pm}}}{|f_{ee}|}\sim 5.3\,\mathrm{TeV}\,.$$

The authors in Ref. [(2)](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1806.08499.pdf) claim that the last result is at the $1\sigma$ level and they present a different bound at $95\%$ C.L.
$$\frac{M_{H^{\pm\pm}}}{|f_{ee}|}\sim \frac{5.3}{\sqrt{3.84^{1/2}}}\,\mathrm{TeV}=3.7\,\mathrm{TeV}\,.$$

How are the authors *translating* the original result into theirs? What is the underlying process or conversion factor? Thanks.

(I asked this question on the [Math site](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4421761/from-1-sigma-to-95-confidence-level-limit?noredirect=1#comment9252930_4421761) but it seems it requires a particle-physics background)

Comment: Is the factor of $\sqrt{3.84^{1/2}}$ something you found in the paper (if so, where?), or something you reverse engineered?

Comment: I suspect that Ref 1 put constraints on $x^2$ (where $x \equiv \frac{M_{H^{\pm\pm}}}{|f_{ee}|}$), since that is a probability so closer to something you would measure than $x$. Then, I think Ref 2 probably divided $x^2$ by $2$ to convert the $1\sigma$ limit to a $2\sigma$ limit (corresponding to a 95% confidence level), and then took the square root, to get a bound on $x$ of $\sqrt{(5.3\ {\rm TeV})^2/2} = 3.7\ {\rm TeV}$. In other words, this is probably a quick and dirty conversion, not a detailed calculation. I am not 100% sure though, so hopefully an expert on this area will answer.

Comment: Thanks, @Andrew. The factor of $\sqrt{3.84^{1/2}}$ was, in fact, provided by one of the authors in private communications. But no further explanation -other than the number itself- was provided.

Comment: It will probably be a number they got from a table of a [quantile function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quantile_function) for some distribution modeling the measurement uncertainty. I don't know which distribution, though. My comment above is assuming a Gaussian distribution... which at least seems to get close numerically.